# popup window will not popup on different window, instead it is displaying on the primary screen on iPad safari

Tags: java, javascript, ipad

```
   popup window will not popup on different window, instead it is displaying on the primary screen on iPad safari browser. works fine on all the other browsers.
       using iframe tag,   


 <div class="formGroup" >
                        <button class="primary" id="" name=""
                        type="button" onClick="somefunction();"  value="">buttonvalue</button>
                        </div>


function some-function(){
        var URL = '<bean:write name="systemDto" property="documenturl"/>'; 
      checks if user want to save or open the document      
       document.form.action = URL+ "?documentName=somedoc";
            form.submit();
             return 0;
          }
```

what needs to add, in order to make this work in iPad browser
        Please help us!!

Comment: code please for `somefunc();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this code for Open popup on different window.

I have added `document.form.target = "_blank";` for opening popup in new window.

```
function somefunc(exptype) {
            getSelectedText();
            var reportURL = '<bean:write name="systemDto" property="documenturl"/>';
            var somevalue = '';
            if (checkFields() > 0) {
                //validating all input parameters 
                //set the export type document.form.elements["Type"].value = exptype; 
                var frm = document.form;
                document.form.elements["sysdto.datavalue"].value = somevalue;
                document.reportForm.action = "getItcLeadsReport.do";
                if (exptype == digitvalue) {
                    document.form.action = URL + "?documentName=somereport";
                     var IS_IPAD = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
                     if (IS_IPAD == true) 
                     {
                       document.form.target = "_blank";
                     }                          
                 }
                frm.submit();
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, when i try like above it is opening in a blank page and then popping up in download window. and our code is working perfectly fine in all the browsers of desktop and laptop. only in iPad safari browser the download popup is not opening on parent screen instead it is displaying on the parent screen. please suggest some script to add which supports the pop-up in iPad safari browser. Thank you very much for the follow up !!

Comment: Is it not a thing what you want?

Comment: not exactly,some script should be added to make pop-up window working in iPad safari browser(any supporting scripts to be added kind of things), without affecting the currently working scenario. Is there any possibility of such fixing. Please suggest!!